# Adding "com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0" manually offline in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I wanted to try FCM in android studio so I followed the procedure as described in firebase start page and docs. but the problem is I can't add "com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0" to android studio. the error says:

```
No cached version of com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0 available for offline mode. Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
```

I've read so many posts here regarding the same problems but as far as I could find they all point out that I should disable offline mode and let android studio install the libraries itself. since there's no way I can connect this computer to internet, please help me find some other way like downloading the necessary library on another computer and manually install it on this one.

I already tried to put these maven repositories:

```
https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/3.1.0#files/com/google/gms/google-services
```

in this address:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google
```

but it didn't solve the problem.

I appreciate any help.